# Не могу связать бд и бэк в Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, backend

Настроил *docker-comose.yml* файл, контейнер собирается нормально, бэк и бд работают нормально, но при этом бэк не может связаться с бд.

**docker-comose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  pg_project:

services:
  backend330:
    image: backend330:latest
    container_name: backend330
    depends_on:
      - pg_db
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules

  pg_db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./.database/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: nftmarketplace
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT:-5436}:5432
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin:
    links:
      - pg_db:pg_db
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
      - .docker.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: nftmarketplace
    networks:
      - postgres

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

**В конфиге бэка:**

```
POSTGRES_LOGIN=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_HOST=pg_db
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_AUTHDATABASE=nftmarketplace
```

**Вылетает такая ошибка:**

```
[Nest] 55 - 01/09/2022, 2:33:48 PM ERROR [SequelizeModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...

SequelizeConnectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN pg_db

at Client._connectionCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:189:24)

at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)

at Client._handleErrorEvent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)

at Connection.emit (node:events:369:20)

at Connection.emit (node:domain:470:12)

at Socket.reportStreamError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:52:12)

at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)

at Socket.emit (node:domain:470:12)

at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)

at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

[image: Контейнер]

Comment: У вас они в разной сети и что логично не видят друг друга, у PG - `networks: - postgres` у `backend330` нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите у всех сервисов опцию:

```
networks:
      - postgres
```

или наоборот добавьте сервис backend330 этот параметр чтобы включить его в общую сеть.